# Can't figure out the meaning of the debugger messages

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

This is a general question for advice about debugging, based on a concrete case.

Here is the message I get, in the Xcode console:

```
2014-07-10 10:54:34.831 MyApp[1975:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2ea83f83 0x391d0ccf 0x2e9ba7cb 0xd18ed 0xcda77 0x10818f 0xcc24b 0x107c87 0x312bb6df 0x313cf9eb 0x312bb6df 0x312ace89 0x312ac64d 0x312ac4bf 0x312abfe5 0x312a9827 0x3131333d 0x3130ffad 0x3130a56b 0x312a66e9 0x312a5851 0x31309ca9 0x338dbaed 0x338db6d7 0x2ea4ea67 0x2ea4ea03 0x2ea4d1d7 0x2e9b7ebf 0x2e9b7ca3 0x31308ed1 0x3130414d 0x108229 0x396ddab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have to say that apart from:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

which gives me a hint on the kind of problem encountered, it seems rather useless to me.

Then I try to get a back trace, running the bt command. I get this:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x3db71, 0x397931f0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x397931f0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x397fd796 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 58
    frame #2: 0x39743fdc libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 76
    frame #3: 0x38a72cd6 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 74
    frame #4: 0x38a8b6e4 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 252
    frame #5: 0x391d0f64 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 192
    frame #6: 0x38a891c6 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
    frame #7: 0x38a88d2c libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 100
    frame #8: 0x391d0e16 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 42
    frame #9: 0x2e9b7f34 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 640
    frame #10: 0x2e9b7ca2 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #11: 0x31308ed0 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 760
    frame #12: 0x3130414c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
  * frame #13: 0x00108228 MyApp `main(argc=1, argv=0x27d59d04) + 116 at main.m:16
(lldb)
```

I also have to admit that the result of the bt command doest not help me much, in finding where in my code something might be wrong.

I hope I am being too negative here and am missing the point of looking at this information the right way.
Could someone tell me how to go in such a case?
Should I run different commands in the debugger console to get something useful or what?

Comment: Did you install debugger break for exception on throw? http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: Use an exception breakpoint.  That will stop at the source of the exception instead of where it bubbled out of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest strategy for diagnosing this sort of error is to launch the application from the Xcode debugger.  Make sure that you set an 'All Exceptions' breakpoint:

1. Show the breakpoint navigator in the left panel.
2. In the lower left corner, hit the '+' button.
3. Select 'Add Exception Breakpoint'

At this point you should have a breakpoint that will stop the program when any exception is detected.  Run your program to the failure point and you should be stopped right on the line where the array bounds error was first detected, rather than at the final global exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Profiling tool with enabling Zombie. If the app crashes, It will show you the exact location of crashing in most of the scenarios.